# Directional derivative of a scalar function $f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{x+y+z}$

Tags: partial-derivative

Given the function:
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{x+y+z}
$$
What's the directional derivative in the direction of the gradient at $(x,y,z) =(1,1,1)$?

I calculated that:
$$
\overrightarrow{\triangledown} f \;\biggr\rvert_{(1,1,1)} = -\frac{1}{9}(1,1,1)
$$

Thus the directional derivative in the direction of the gradient at $(1,1,1)$ is:
$$
\left(\overrightarrow{\triangledown} f \;\biggr\rvert_{(1,1,1)}\right) 
\cdot 
\widehat{\left(\overrightarrow{\triangledown} f \;\biggr\rvert_{(1,1,1)}\right)}
=
-\frac{1}{9}(1,1,1) \cdot \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1) = - 3\sqrt{3}
$$

But that answer was marked as false. Why?

Comment: I think you wrote some wrong computations. The last equality is wrong. $-\frac{1}{9}(1,1,1) \cdot \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1) = - \frac{1}{27}\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I don't understand how I missed that! I blame the late hour..! But I think that you're almost correct - shouldn't it be $-\frac{1}{9\sqrt{3}}$ ?.

Comment: Typically directional derivatives are defined for _unitary_ vectors, then you must divide the gradient by its norm, but do not change the sign of the vector: the result is always positive. This I think is the main point.

Comment: Jesus RS: I don't understand - the norm of the gradient is positive, so diving the gradient (which is negative) by its norm (positive), will stay negative.

Comment: @Dor You might say $-\frac{1}{9\sqrt{3}}$, you might say $-\frac{1}{27}\sqrt3$. They're the same. To see this, expand the first fraction by $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Back to the sign, you put only a minus, and there must be two, and teh final result positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably worth while doing a general case first.  The directional derivative of $f$ at $P$ in the direction $\bf u$ is
$$\nabla f(P)\cdot\widehat{\bf u}\ .$$
For the question you asked we have ${\bf u}=\nabla f(P)$ so this becomes
$$\nabla f(P)\cdot\widehat{\nabla f(P)}\ .$$
But for any vector ${\bf v}$ we have
$${\bf v}=\|{\bf v}\|\widehat{\bf v}\quad\hbox{so}\quad
  {\bf v}\cdot\widehat{\bf v}
  =\|{\bf v}\|(\widehat{\bf v}\cdot\widehat{\bf v})=\|{\bf v}\|$$
(note that this is always positive, as mentioned in the comment by Jesus RS) and the final answer, using your calculation, is just
$$\|\nabla f(P)\|=\frac1{3\sqrt3}\ .$$

Comment: Why $\|\nabla f(P)\|=\frac1{3\sqrt3}\ $ ? It should be: $$\|\nabla f(P)\| = \|-\frac{1}{9}(1,1,1)\| = \|(-\frac{1}{9},-\frac{1}{9},-\frac{1}{9})\| = \sqrt{(-\frac{1}{9},-\frac{1}{9},-\frac{1}{9}) \cdot (-\frac{1}{9},-\frac{1}{9},-\frac{1}{9})} = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{9^2} = \frac{1}{27}$$

Comment: You didn't take the $\sqrt{\ }$.